# NHibernate mappings

Tags: c#, nhibernate

If I have a customer table with fields : Address1, Address2, Address3 - Is it possible to map these fields into one array of strings? So from an implementating point of view I would want to call Customer.Address[0] ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to map to three fields and use a separate indexer property to provide access.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [dynamic components](http://www.mattfreeman.co.uk/2009/01/nhibernate-mapping-with-dynamic-component/), it will however return an IDictionary